# Can't put logotype in top left corner without moving the nav menu

Tags: css, html, alignment, inline

I am working with a school project and try to do remake a webbsite. Is there someone who knows how I can put my EA logo in the top left corner without moving the navigation menu? 
Here is the html:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/style.css">
    <title>FIFA 16</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="ealogo"><img src="img/ealogo.png" alt="ealogo"</div>
        <a href="index.htm" target="_self" class="fifafont">FIFA</a>
        <a href="" target="_self">ULTIMATE TEAM&trade;</a>
        <a href="" target="_self">NYHETER</a>
        <a href="" target="_self">MER</a>
        <a href="" target="_self">KÖP</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
    body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #fff;
}

    .nav {
padding: 15px;
text-align: center;
font-family: lato;
font-size: 20px;
color: white;
background-color: black;
width: 100%;
}

    a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
margin: 25px;
}

    .fifafont {
font-family: fifawelcome;
font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Just use `float: left` on logo https://jsfiddle.net/rxdrvLqm/

Comment: Change the width of the nav and float it right with display:inline-block. Then float your image left. Can you create a jsfiddle or jsbin?

Answer (score 0):

All I did was give the logo an id and float left with a margin to correct the padding so it is in the top left corner.

```
#ealogo{

    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    float: left;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rrjw1zck/2/)